# How to add condition in didExitRegion when all the Estimotes in the area cannot be detected

Tags: ios, ibeacon, estimote

Here is our scenario:

> We plan to setup around 4 beacons in huge room (i.e. like a department store). Once the user goes in the room, the application will notify the user, "Welcome to our shop!". When the user leaves the room, the application will then notify the user, "Please come again!".
>   The reason why we plan to place 4 beacons is that to make sure that while the beacons are in range with the device, we can make sure that the user is really still in the room. (Our worry is the user might still be in the room and the notification for saying "Please come again!" appears.)

We would like to know if it is possible to code that if the mobile device could not scan for all the beacons, the user has already left the regions and the device will send a local notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for this to work you need to:

1. Make sure you have full coverage of the store with the radio range of your beacons.
2. Set the identifiers on the beacons so they share a ProximityUUID.
3. Define a region that matches all the beacons (e.g. the region should define the ProximityUUID and leave the major and minor null).
4. Monitor for this region.
5. In the `didExitRegion` callback, start a three second timer that only sends the exit notification if you do not get a `didEnterRegion` callback in this period.  This is needed because iOS sometimes sends a spurious exit event followed by an enter event a second later.
6. If the timer goes off without an enter event, only then send the exit local notification.

Comment: Should the identifiers of all of our beacons in the same region the same though? Also, if I leave the major and minor to null, that means if I go to a store, there's a possibility that I could detect the beacons that are not mine?

Comment: You should set the ProximityUUID on all beacons to a new value that is unique to you.  That way, if you ever see that UUID, you have a good of an idea as possible that the beacons are yours.  And while not required, I would recommend you set each beacon to have a different minor value so you can tell them apart.

Comment: Oh. and according to the steps you provided, are we suppose to use monitoring instead of ranging?

Comment: Yes, monitoring works well for your use case because you get a callback for entry the first time any beacon is seen, and one for exit once no beacons are seen anymore.